# Deleting on a shared drive gives false error, why?

Tags: windows-server-2012, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I use terminal-server Windows Server 2012 when a user inside the terminal session deletes a file on a shared drive (R: here) and gets the error bellow:

```
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in
R:\SHARE\etc
Verify the item's location and try again
```

[image]

The file is there and the file is indeed deleted, but in order to see it deleted in explorer, you need to press the F5 button to refresh the screen.

**Later edit:**

It seems that this happens only for `.xlsx` files

This is, how can I reproduce the problem:

- create file in `R:\SHARE`. Call it `test.xlsx`
- when I try to delete the file, I get the error
- create file in `R:\SHARE`. Call it `test.txt`
- when I try to delete the file, no error is displayed

Why this false error happens and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you do know what <kbd>F5</kbd> does in Windows [Explorer], right?  It refreshes your view.

So that's not a "false error," it's an accurate description of what's happened.  The file can't be deleted because it's no longer there.  It's no longer there, because someone already deleted it, and your file listing hasn't updated since the delete.

As to what's happening with `.xlsx` files... well, it sounds like there's a script or process monitoring that folder to move or delete `.xlsx` files.  Presumably, for a reason... might want to track down that reason before you go changing things.